# SQL Query to select records without duplicate values

Tags: sql, request

Could you help me with sql request. I have a table with three columns:

- response id;
- value from;
- value to.

There are different `Response id` values in the table.

I need to write request/query to get all possible values from columns "value from" and "value to" associated with current `Response id` without duplicates.

[image: Please see screenshot]

Thank you in advance

Andre

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `union`:

```
select response_id, value_from as target
from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select response_id, value_to as target
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you. It is what I need

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Select distinct response_id,target from (
select response_id, value_from as target
from t1
union all
select response_id, value_to as target
from t1 ) as t2
```